# Google Chart not displaying with the correct height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I'm having this problem with my google graph displaying in the default size (width: 400px and Height: 200px) while I want it to be a different size. I'm wondering if this has something to do with it being In a partial view or something, but it does sometimes display correct if I change the size in the code and refresh. If you could help me out thanks in advance.

```js
@model ProjectServerside.PresentationModels.PMData

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'bar'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Element', 'Count', { role: 'annotation' }],
            ['Threads',@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ThreadCount), 'Threads'],
            ['Votes', @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VoteCount), 'Votes'],
            ['Comments',@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CommentCount), 'Comments'],
          ]);

          var options = {
              chart: {
                  title: 'Interest Performance',
                  subtitle: 'Threads, Votes, and Comments',
                  width: 900,
                  height: 500
              }              
          };

          var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('graph'));

          chart.draw(data, options);
      }
</script>
<div id="graph" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

is not missing since it's on the layout html file thus is included in the header. Again if you could help me with this thank you in advance.

[This is how it displays on the page now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsyDC.png)

Comment: I would recommend removing the `style` attribute from the `div` and using the chart `options` to control the size. keep in mind, there is an overall `height` and `width` along with a `chartArea: height` and `width`, which doesn't include the axis labels or legend...

Comment: @WhiteHat ,Thank you for the comment. I tried as you suggested,but it doesn't really solve the problem, still shows up as the default values as I mentioned above. I think this maybe might have something to do with it being a partial view (returned from the controller) and not loading the options properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no width/height-[properties](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options) for `options.chart`

You must define `width` and `height` as properties of `options`

```
var options = {
                  width: 900,
                  height: 500,
                  chart: {
                           title: 'Interest Performance',
                           subtitle: 'Threads, Votes, and Comments'                      
                         }              
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure you include the semi-colon after your height.

```
<div id="graph" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```